# How to auto-populate specific column items from another list with related item

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, lookup-column

Salute comrades,

So, i have two different lists say, `ListUn` and `Listdeux`, the fist one "`ListUn`" having items `Test1` & `Test2` under the fist column `TestP`and second column `ColToPopulate` ( see attached pic for visuals [First List Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRa1u.png) ),that has to fetch data from the second list "`Listdeux`" under column `ColToPopulate` that has unique items related to fist list's column `TestP` items correspondingly ( see attached pic for visuals [Second List Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sK2K5.png) ).

What i am trying to archive is having `ListUn`'s second column `ColToPopulate` to fetch and populate data from `Listdeux` **Automatically** and assign the items correponding the specific related item form the second list. The only column that is supposed to be filled is from the second list.

NOTE: What i have managed to do so far is setting up the column type to `lookup` and assigning the items manually(But what i want is this to happen automatically by looking up what as changed from the `Listdeux`

I hope i have at least explained the point

Comment: You can write a javascript function which query this data for you and then refer this function in presave() method on newform.

Answer (score 1):

For your requirement, I suggest you change the type of ColToPopulate column in TestUn list to “Multiple lines of text”, an then you can create a SharePoint 2013 workflow with “Call HTTP Web Service” action and “Update List Item” action in SharePoint Designer, the detailed steps as below:

[image]

[image]

Then in the workflow settings, we can select “start workflow automatically when an item is created” in Start Options section:

[image]

Finally, when a new item created in Listdeux list, the ColToPopulate column in TestUn list is updated.

For the existing items, you can start the workflow manually.

Comment: So i tried adding the workflow from SharePoint 365, but some how i only get 2010 workflow, basically there is no option to choose between the 2013 and 2010 workflow. see the pic https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUTsO.png

Note, i don't have access to open the site on SharePoint Designer and i am not the Global admin. Thanks in adv

Comment: The OOTB workflow cannot achieve the requirement. If you can use SharePoint Designer, you need to install workflow manager to create a custom workflow via SharePoint 2013 workflow platform.

Comment: And that is the problem, i can't use SharePoint Designer, and its something that i can't do anything about(even requesting access)

Comment: Btw, i was wondering its possible to archive everything with Flow(i know nothing about it though)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to populate you can just add additional column in display. When configuring the lookup field just use the option 'Add column to show each of these additional fields' then that fields shows up as new column in the second list.

Answer (score 1):

Without automating a "copy" of the data as Hellofiona suggested, or coding a script that pulls from the REST api, there's no inherent way to show related items that are 1:Many in this fashion, at least not in the list view.

You CAN do this in the profile view (DispForm.aspx) quite easily, if that helps you at all. Basically you open up the profile page for ListUn and edit it, then add a list webpart for ListDuex. Then connect the "CurrentItem" to filter the items from the list webpart for ListDuex. With a bit of css and maybe some javascript to move things around, you can make it look like a decent "Profile" page with related or "detail" items displaying alongside the "master" record.

Again, this might not be what you intended, but it is an alternative to the problem that doesn't require coding to pull off (unless you want to get fancy with the UI side of it).